# Finding the value of a definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the value of the following integral
$$ I = \int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{e^{\sin x}}{e^{\sin x}+e^{-\sin x}}\,dx$$

My attempt: I tried to evaluate this by the property of even/odd functions for definite integrals, but found that the function is neither even nor odd. Further, I found that the function is symmetric with respect to $ x = {\pi}/2 $. But I am not getting an away to proceed to the next step.

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: Make the substitution $u = -x$ and look at it for a while.

Comment: Try substituting $-x$ for $x$.

Comment: Thanks to @LordSharktheUnknown & DanielFischer. I got the clue.

Answer (score 4):

$$ I = \int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{e^{\sin x}}{e^{\sin x}+e^{-\sin x}}\,dx......(1)$$
Substituting $ u = -x $, we get 
$$ I = \int_{\pi}^{-\pi}\frac{-e^{-\sin u}}{e^{-\sin u}+e^{\sin u}}\,du$$
$$or, I = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{-\sin u}}{e^{\sin u}+e^{-\sin u}}\,du$$
$$or, I = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{-\sin x}}{e^{\sin x}+e^{-\sin x}}\,du.....(2)$$

Adding (1) & (2) we get,

$$2I = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{\sin u}+e^{-\sin u}}{e^{\sin u}+e^{-\sin u}}\,du= 2{\pi}$$
$$or, I = \pi$$

Answer (score 2):

Formally:
$$I=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{e^{\sin x}}{e^{\sin x}+e^{-\sin x}}\,dx$$
Flipping the domain of integration takes $x$ to $-x$ and preserves the value, while swapping $\sin x$ and $-\sin x$:
$$I=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{e^{-\sin x}}{e^{\sin x}+e^{-\sin x}}\,dx$$
Add together:
$$2I=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{e^{\sin x}+e^{-\sin x}}{e^{\sin x}+e^{-\sin x}}\,dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi1\,dx=2\pi$$
and thus $I=\frac{2\pi}2=\pi$.